# How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application when building a JavaFX application into a JAR file?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I have a JavaFX application that works fine when I run it inside IntelliJ IDEA, but when I try to build it into an executable JAR file, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
 at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
 at com.example.song_finder_fx.App.main(App.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  javafx.application.Application
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) … 10 more
```

I have searched many resources and found that this error is related to some JAR files from JavaFX SDK (‘javafx.controls’, ‘javafx.fxml’). But I have added all the used libraries to the artifact when building the JAR file, including these two JAR files.

I am using Java SDK 19, JavaFX 21-ea+24 with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Packaging JavaFX applications is not that simple, see https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX.

Comment: Packaging info is in the [javafx tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info), also see [openjfx info on runtime images](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular).  Also, don't use the `ea` distributions - those are early access versions of software that may be less stable and reliable than a standard (non-ea) distribution.

Comment: If your application is completely modular, then I advise creating a zip of your application using [jlink](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options) (or `jpackage`, e.g. via JPackageScriptFX only if you need a more professional installer or have a non-modular project or automatic module dependencies).  If you use the Idea new JavaFX project wizard and run the maven javafx:jlink goal on the resultant project, it will create a redistributable image for you in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a fat jar.

**For modular application**

You can create a JavaFX application with IntelliJ with the build management Tool Maven or Gradle. There is a Maven/Gradle command for creating the jar by default. Look how it is done there.

**For non modular project**

If you use Gradle (instead of Maven), you can take a look at this sample application on my GitHub:

https://github.com/davidweber411/SimpleJavaFxAppWithoutModules

There is a Gradle Task "createCustomFatJar" which creates the complete executable jar.